# MVC Controller Will Not Create Record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to create a new record with the Create action it fails but there is no errors it's just not there. I'm not exactly sure why its not or why there isn't an error. I'm using a Search action to populate some of the fields in the Create action then filling in the rest of the information.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Incident incident)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Incidents.AddObject(incident);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.IncidentCreatedBy = new SelectList(db.Creators, "CreatorID", "CreatorName", incident.IncidentCreatedBy);
        ViewBag.ErrorType = new SelectList(db.Errors, "ErrorID", "ErrorDescription", incident.ErrorType);
        ViewBag.IncidentID = new SelectList(db.IncidentItems, "IncidentID", "IncidentItem1", incident.IncidentID);
        ViewBag.IncidentReasonID = new SelectList(db.IncidentReasons, "IncidentReasonID", "ReasonDescription", incident.IncidentReasonID);
        ViewBag.IncidentResolutionID = new SelectList(db.IncidentResolutions, "IncidentResolutionID", "ResolutionDescription", incident.IncidentResolutionID);
        ViewBag.InventoryStatus = new SelectList(db.InventoryStatus, "InvStatusID", "InvStatusValue", incident.InventoryStatus);
        ViewBag.ShipperID = new SelectList(db.ShipperIDs, "ShipperID1", "ShipperName", incident.ShipperID);
        return View(incident);
    }

public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {
        Incident i = new Incident();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            Tracking result = db1.Trackings.FirstOrDefault(r => r.OrderNum == searchString);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                i.Email = result.Email;
                i.OriginalShipDate = result.ShipDate;
                i.Name = result.Name;
                i.OrderID = result.OrderNum;
                i.IncidentReasonID = 1;

                ViewBag.IncidentCreatedBy = new SelectList(db.Creators, "CreatorID", "CreatorName", i.IncidentCreatedBy);
                ViewBag.ErrorType = new SelectList(db.Errors, "ErrorID", "ErrorDescription", i.ErrorType);
                ViewBag.IncidentID = new SelectList(db.IncidentItems, "IncidentID", "IncidentItem1", i.IncidentID);
                ViewBag.IncidentReasonID = new SelectList(db.IncidentReasons, "IncidentReasonID", "ReasonDescription", i.IncidentReasonID);
                ViewBag.IncidentResolutionID = new SelectList(db.IncidentResolutions, "IncidentResolutionID", "ResolutionDescription", i.IncidentResolutionID);
                ViewBag.InventoryStatus = new SelectList(db.InventoryStatus, "InvStatusID", "InvStatusValue", i.InventoryStatus);
                ViewBag.ShipperID = new SelectList(db.ShipperIDs, "ShipperID1", "ShipperName", i.ShipperID);


                return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Create.cshtml", i);
            }
        }
        else { return View(); }

    }

//search view
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){    
     <p> Order #: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
    } 
@if(IsPost){}

--create view
@model RMA_MAID_EASY.Models.Incident

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<script type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});    
</script>




<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<fieldset>
<legend>Incidents</legend>
<table>

    @*<tbody>*@
        <tr>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID)</div>      <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderID)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalShipDate)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OriginalShipDate)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OriginalShipDate)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentReasonID, "IncidentReason")</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("IncidentReasonID", String.Empty)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentReasonID)</div></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentResolutionID, "IncidentResolution")</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("IncidentResolutionID", String.Empty)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentResolutionID)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)</div></td>
            @*<td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnTagRequired)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnTagRequired)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnTagRequired)</div></td>*@
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReturnTagRequired)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RefundRequired, new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Y", "Yes"}, {"N", "No"} },"key", "value", Model.RefundRequired))</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateRetTagGenerated)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateRetTagGenerated, new { id = "datepicker", type = "text" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRetTagGenerated)</div></td>
            @*<td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefundRequired)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RefundRequired)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefundRequired)</div></td>*@

            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefundRequired)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RefundRequired, new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Y", "Yes"}, {"N", "No"} },"key", "value", Model.RefundRequired)) </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor ="#D3D3D3">

            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefundAmount)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RefundAmount)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefundAmount)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateRefundIssued)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateRefundIssued)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRefundIssued)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShipperID, "ShipperID1")</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("ShipperID", String.Empty)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShipperID)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.InventoryItem)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.InventoryItem)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InventoryItem)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.InventoryQuantity)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.InventoryQuantity)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InventoryQuantity)</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.eBayCredit)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.eBayCredit)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eBayCredit)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.eBayCreditFileDate)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.eBayCreditFileDate)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eBayCreditFileDate)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LostValue)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LostValue)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LostValue)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentCreatedBy, "Creator")</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("IncidentCreatedBy", String.Empty)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentCreatedBy)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentReturnDate)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IncidentReturnDate)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentReturnDate)</div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor ="#D3D3D3">
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentResolved)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IncidentResolved)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentResolved)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentReceived)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IncidentReceived)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentReceived)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShippingCost)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShippingCost)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShippingCost)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IncidentCreatedDate)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IncidentCreatedDate)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentCreatedDate)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RMANumber)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RMANumber)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RMANumber)</div></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>                
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RMARequested)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RMARequested)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RMARequested)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RestockOption)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RestockOption)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RestockOption)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReceivedNotes)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReceivedNotes)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReceivedNotes)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.InventoryStatus, "InventoryStatu")</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("InventoryStatus", String.Empty)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InventoryStatus)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ErrorType, "Error")</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("ErrorType", String.Empty)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ErrorType)</div></td>

        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor ="#D3D3D3">
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReplacementOption)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReplacementOption)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReplacementOption)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Replacement)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Replacement)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Replacement)</div></td>
            <td><div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OurShippingCost)</div><div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OurShippingCost)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OurShippingCost)</div>


        </tr>

    @*</tbody>
*@</table>
<p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </p>

</fieldset>
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails?" Does it not save? Does it skip over the save? Is Incident null? Where are you redirected to?

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is pointing to the correct database?  It might actually be saving, but if you're looking at the wrong database you won't see it.  This is easy to do if you're using Code First, because many times it creates a new database using convention naming.

Comment: This was a database first design and the index and edit actions work. This is one of the first MVC projects I've done so this is a major learning curve. After I try to create the record it sends me back to my Search view. Also how do I tell if the model state is valid, add a watch to @model.

Comment: This might help you quite a bit:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCPt9aOcd98

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the top of the Create method and start debugging.  Trigger the Create method from the app and step through the code.  Hover over variables and such to see their value at any given point.  This will likely tell you exactly what's happening.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Next time you post a question, please try to describe the problem with more details. Posting a lot of code won't help people to answer, usually.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say ... few things you could do:
 - Use firebug to see what params are being posted back to your action
 - Set a few breakpoints around your Create action to see if the correct objects/values are being dealt with.